Multi select in APS viewer does not pick nodes that are covered behind or inside target nodes
As shown on this video, using the BoxSelection extension in the APS viewer, nodes that are either inside of targetted components or covered behind are not being selected.
Is there any sort of configuration to the BoxSelection extension or a different extension that would allow for multiselection of everything within the selection box including covered nodes?
I was looking here for the documentation of the BoxSelection extension, but could not find anything related.

the way this extension works is, it reads from readbackBuffer for pixel matching with object ids. Since there will be an overlap for a few objects that are behind and completely covered by other large objects, those objects are not selected.
source code reference in browser: under developer tools->source-> page->LMV->src->wgs->render->RenderContext.js->Line number #1901.
An alternate solution would be, to explore getting all the objects in custom viewing frustum.

BTW, you can explode the model a bit and do the BoxSelection, all the objects will get selected.

@varunpatil do you know of any publicly available example of getting all the objects in custom viewing frustum? also thanks for the explode tip, maybe that'll be good enough of a solution

unfortunately, we don't have an example of custom viewing frustum, we'll take it as a blog request and try to publish it soon.  for now, explode should work as a temporary solution.

alright, thanks for taking the request, anyway explode should more or less do the trick for the case I'm showing on the vid, but for cases where there are other surrounding nodes it'll not do

in that case, you have to explode it a bit more. It would help me to know what you're trying to achieve by selecting all the objects. Please book a call here: https://calendly.com/autodesk-platform-services with either me or Petr Broz or Michael Beale, depending on the time zone preference

alright, will book a session, thanks... but for now just imagine a situation where you have a large assembly of a machine that consists of deeply nested nodes, say 6 or more levels deep, the way the explode extension works is that it kinda starts moving away nodes from higher assemblies in the node hierarchy at first and then once you move the slider further the lower child subasseblies start to dismantle, so that means different subassemblies could collide with each other

I believe you are looking for this:
viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.BoxSelection').boxSelectionTool.useGeometricIntersection = true


I checked the box selection after exploding. unfortunately, not everything is selected. So, setting useGeometricIntersection to true is not the solution
https://imgur.com/cVTycba

Strangely, it works in my model. link
It seems there are too many small parts in your model. I remember that when set to true, it will check the bounding boxes of the fragments. Anyway, if your model doesn't have too many parts, you should create a new extension, get all the information of the fragment geometry, and check using Three.js Frustum.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@thanh trang Nguyen in our case it's too many tiny parts, like bolts, washers, nuts, etc., but thank you

so, I've decided to go with this solution after talking to @petr-broz today, cause he also brought it up and said it's kind of slow but I think that's to be expected, thank you
